# Divs float within wrapper not showing up

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float

I'm using the Bootstrap Framework, but like to make my own navigation. I found 2 divs I made inside a wrapper with floats are not showing up, not sure why.
http://heidixu.com/misc/nav_div/

The structure is like this:

```
<div class="navBar-wrapper">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="navItems"></div>
</div>

.navBar-wrapper {
    max-width:1170px;
    background-color:black;
    height:45px;
    padding-left:15px;
    padding-right:15px;
    z-index:99999;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    position:relative;
}

.logo {
    width:100px;
    background-color:green;
    float:left;
}

.navItems {
    float:right;
    background-color:red;
    width:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are empty, thus height is zero.  Use a tool like firebug or Chrome dev tools to inspect your page as it is to discover this.

To fix it, you could do any of the following:

```
.logo {
    width:100px;
    height:44px;
    background-color:green;
    float:left;
}

.navItems {
    float:right;
    background-color:red;
    width:100px;
    height:44px;
}
```

Or better yet, this will work dynamically:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var navheight = $(".navBar-wrapper").height;
    $(".logo").css("height",navheight);
    $(".navItems").css("height",navheight);

});
```

Or finally, look a little deeper into Bootstrap's examples.  The "navbar-brand" and "navbar-text" classes come to mind.

Good luck, I hope that helps!

Comment: I did forgot about height. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You provided a `width` of `100px` to both elements, however you omitted `height`.